# How to serialize reverse relationship in protobuf

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, reverse

I have the following proto file

```
message Person {

    // ID
    required int32 id = 1;

    // name
    required string name = 2;

    // email
    optional string email = 3;

    // tasks
    repeated Task tasks = 4;
}

message Task {
    //ID
    required int32 id = 1;

    //owner
    optional Person owner =2;

}
```

person has list of tasks, which is one-many relationship. 
In task, I set the reverse relationship to person, which is one-one relationship.

My question is: how to serialize the reverse relationship to current person in task when I build task in person object since person object is not built yet. please refer to ???? (question mark) part in the following code snippet.
I have the following code for serialization.

```
PersonMsg.Person.Builder personBuilder = PersonMsg.Person.newBuilder();  
    personBuilder.setId(1);  
    personBuilder.setName("Alex");  
    personBuilder.setEmail("alex@gmail.com");  
    personBuilder.addTasks(PersonMsg.Task.newBuilder()
                            .setId(11)
                            .setOwner("??????"));
    personBuilder.addTasks(PersonMsg.Task.newBuilder()
                            .setId(12)
                            .setOwner("???????"));
    PersonMsg.Person xxg = personBuilder.build();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so a Person has Tasks, and a Task has a Person (owner). Does this mean the task could have another Person as an owner?

Comment: I want to set current person as owner to task. For deserialization, once I deserialize person in stack, I can visit this person object by visiting task.owner. this is reverse relationship from task to person. Current person has ID 1,  so I want to set current person object with ID 1 to task.owner.

Comment: but right now you create a circular dependency not a reverse one. Person has Tasks, so it owns them, so you don't need to specify person in tasks, there's already composition between the two objects.

Comment: I just have a test.After deserializing person, I get  Person.tasks. I loop in tasks, I get one task from it. I check the value for task.getOwner.getId(). it is 0.(if the reverse is set by default, it should be 1) So it means task.owner is not set when I serialize it. The question is how to set a reverse relationship when serializing person .

Comment: Hi, wheee. thanks for your reply. so the question may be :  can we do circular relationships in protobuf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a circular dependency and you need to resolve it otherwise the program won't compile.

There is already composition between `Person` and `Task` since `Task` is a member of `Person`. Basically you wouldn't need to link `Task` to `Person` as there's already an existing link.

If you really need a double link, I would suggest using a message reference (like a foreign key) to the Person object.

```
message Task {
    //ID
    required int32 id = 1;
    //owner
    optional int32 ownerId =2; //which is the owner Person id.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because Protocol Buffers does not support pointers. The `tasks` field of `Person` doesn't store pointers to tasks, it stores the actual tasks. And the `owner` field of `Task` doesn't store a pointer to a person, it stores a full `Person`. You cannot have two different `Task`s that have the same `owner`, because that would require pointers.

This implies that a Protobuf message is always strictly a tree. This differs from Java in general, where objects form an arbitrary graph, possibly with cycles.

The solution is to have the `owner` field of `Task` store the *ID* of a person, rather than storing a full `Person`. Then your code will need to know how to look up the `Person` given the ID.